# dual boot ubuntu & lubunut on laptop: how can one be safely never updated?

Tags: networking, dual-boot, partitioning, updates, lubuntu

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 alongside Lubuntu 14.04 on a Dell Latitude E6410 laptop (just took all defaults; wizard did all the work).  Seems to work great, but doing updates on both OS's is more work.  **I only want to use Lubuntu for a single task (playback of audio)**, and internet access and software updates are not needed for the one task I use Lubuntu for.  **I wish I could set things up so that I can safely skip doing updates in Lubuntu**.  Ubuntu is to be regularly updated and go online.  Is doing the following simple things enough to make it as if Lubuntu is running with the internet disconnected?

```
sudo ufw default deny incoming
sudo ufw default deny outgoing
slide physical wireless on/off switch on side of laptop to off position
```

### More chatter and worrying:

Ubuntu on the laptop is to safely/securely access the internet and receive regular updates.  Lubuntu and Ubuntu appear to be on separate partitions.  When in one, the partition with the other one appears to be unmounted by default.  They seem pretty separate, but I am no expert.  It is likely that sometimes I will mount the Lubuntu partition accidentally when running Ubuntu, due to clumsy mouse action in a file manager.  Naturally I will often forget to put the wireless on/off switch in the right position for Lubuntu vs Ubuntu.

I have an old desktop machine running I think xubuntu that is not connected to the internet (and has no wireless card) and hasn't had updates in years (another single-task device), and it runs fine.  It is idiot-proof because the ethernet is disconnected.  I want to get the same effect with the Lubuntu partition of the laptop, but am suspicious of a laptop because of it's wireless capability; I am not sure it is truly offline.  I want Ubuntu to have wifi, so I don't want to remove the wireless card from the laptop.

Yeah this seems dangerous but time is also valuable and doing system updates takes time.

I should just figure out another single-purpose device for audio playback at some point (a mini PC?), but the laptop works great...